# Linkedin 403 Forbidden Error while getting connections email and name in JSApi

Tags: javascript, api, linkedin-api

I'm trying to get email, name and picture from connections, but when the user authenticates, I get the error "GET https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections:(picture-url,first-name,email-address)?count=30 403 (Forbidden) "

I'm posting my code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    api_key: uey3banalp6s
    authentication: true
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function loadData() {
    IN.API.Connections("me")
    .fields(["pictureUrl","firstName","emailAddress"])
    .params({"count":30})
    .result(function(result) {
    profHTML = "";
    for (var index in result.values) {
    profile = result.values[index]
    if (profile.pictureUrl) {
    profHTML += "email:" + profile.emailAddress;
    profHTML += "name:" + profile.firstName;
    profHTML += "<img class=img_border height=30 align=\"left\" src=\"" + profile.pictureUrl + "\">";
    }
    }
    $("#connections").html(profHTML);
    });
    }

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="connections"></div>
    <script type="IN/Login" data-onAuth="loadData">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The "forbidden" usually indicates that you forgot to set up your authentication correctly (so the system knows its you thats trying to get the data) or that you are trying to get the data from the wrong url (and the data from that other url is something you do not have permissions to)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API doesn't understand 'authentication: true'. It should be 'authorize: true'.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    api_key: uey3banalp6s
    authorize: true
</script>
```

Comment: I fail to see how you can have JS object notation floating around outside of an object and it actually understands it. I upvoted your answer to replace mine in case you are actually correct. Do you have any link to an explanation or can you explain how this is possible?

Comment: Regretfully, I can not explain how this works, as I do not understand it myself. However, that this is in fact the way to do it is easily checked here: http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/getting-started-javascript-api

See point 5; Fetch authorization automatically

Answer (score 1):

Change your script initialization code to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    api_key: your_api_key
    authentication: true
    scope: r_basicprofile r_emailaddress
</script>
```

This should make your script properly work. You were missing the scope permissions. More info: [Profile Fields permisssions](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-fields)

Answer (score 0):

The script the comes first, where you're loading LinkedIn, is a mess. You need to put your API key in quotes because otherwise JavaScript thinks that clusterbomb of crypto is a variable name. Secondly, you're using a colon in what appears to be an assignment, but you aren't within an object literal. Try using

```
api_key = "uey3banalp6s";
authentication = true;
```

Comment: -1: This answer is incorrect. The api-key is given as per spec from LinkedIn. I do the same, and it works as it should.

Comment: 'authentication' should be 'authorize' though, but without the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I was pretty sure you couldn't do this (but apparently there are hacks available to allow it)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    api_key: uey3banalp6s   //nothing in here gets used if src is set
    authentication: true    //even if it did it would be "=" not ":"
</script>
```

put Keith's answer in your other script tag

Comment: You'd be better off just voting him up.

Comment: @Daedalus I would have, but it was missing the source enclosed in src'd script tag, which was too unwieldy to put in a comment.  I guess I could have edited it though...

Comment: U mean to tell me that JavaScript actually does understand what is inside of those script tags?

Comment: nope it just ignores them try for yourself, add:
`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js?">
alert("fna i was wrong");</script>`
and best of all it won't even error in the console ... good place to put comments on the api though I guess